# UPI : Deep linking URL with signing

Tags: angular, hyperlink, payment, deep-linking, upi

I'm Building an website & it has a payment button. I'm not much interested to integrate any payment gateway. I want the website to **redirect to the UPI apps** and the user can enter the amount and pay there when they use it on mobile.

So I'm using **UPI intent flow** to redirect users to the UPI apps, but the payment in failing in all UPI apps like gpay, phonepay, whatsapp, paytm etc.

**Sample : upi://pay?pa=9000000009@upi&pn=User1&tn=Test UPI&am=20&cu=INR&mc=1234&tr=01234**

I found that since we are using personal UPI Ids in the UPI intent its failing and if we  use business/merchant UPI Ids it will work.

**Query :** How come a QR-Code in many shop works which has individual UPI Ids, while the URL Intent alone for that personal UPI Id is not working.
**Example :** I have an Customer with an QR code in his shop which is not registered as Merchant and the users can able to scan and pay in the shop, when i use the same UPI Id from QR to the UPI Intent its failing. Why its failing?

I found some thing in the UPI document like signature (**1.3 Signature**) in which it says to generate a key pair and share it to NPCI in offline mode. Can we as a end-user do it? How to achieve this signing of the UPI Intent?

My end goal is to Just **redirect to the UPI Payment Apps** and nothing more than that, Not to integrate any payment gateways in the website.

[UPI Documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20200921110005/https://www.npci.org.in/sites/default/files/UPI%20Linking%20Specs_ver%201.6.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently found that **paytmmp** keywork works, When we construct the URL with this keyword and the payment get accepted.

This works even with the non-merchant (Individual) UPI Id's.

**paytmmp://pay?pa=9000000009@upi&pn=User1&tn=Test UPI&am=20&cu=INR&mc=1234&tr=01234**

Need some kind of solution for **Gpay** & **phonepe** also.

Comment: yes it work fine for me but i am not getting any response back while user make a successful payment

Answer (score 0):

`Google Pay` and `Phonepe` use this.

**GPAY - tez**:- `tez://upi/pay?pa=9000000009@upi&pn=User1&tn=Test UPI&am=20&cu=INR&mc=1234&tr=01234`

**PHONEPAY - phonepe**:- `phonepe://pay?pa=9000000009@upi&pn=User1&tn=Test UPI&am=20&cu=INR&mc=1234&tr=01234`

Answer (score 0):

I think according to new updates we can't use all UPI in intent payment.
I used myupi@sbi UPI and it worked for me
So suggest you to use your banks official UPI I'd.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is it still working?

Comment: It works sometimes 

Comment: VPA needs to be whitelisted. so according to new update only current accounts linked with VPA works with Intents. QR codes works just fine with any VPA